# Failed to compile in a next.js project

Tags: next.js, compiler-errors, package, react-toastify

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (21:3)

I visit all the files but can't get any error. What can I do now?

This problem I face when only I work in my branch but in other branch there have no problem. App is running very well.

Now please anyone help me How can I overcome this.

I have already try

✔ new git cloning
✔ remove node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall npm
✔ update react-toastify plugin